# remove_action wc_empty_cart_message not working in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to REMOVE completely the `wc_empty_cart_message`. My site has no cart. and when the item is removed from checkout the user is redirected to the home page. But then upon browsing to a shop page, the message "your cart is not available whilst your checkout is empty" appears and is completely unnecessary.

I have seen many of questions/answers about how to change the message to something else (I tried some of them which also did not seem to work).

I tried this which seems to be the right thing to do, but for some reason it does not make any visible change on my website.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
```

Is there any way to check which hook is creating the message from the front-end? Or any way how I can see what is overruling this command from executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the "Your cart is currently empty" message, use:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_is_empty() {
    // Remove
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'action_woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 9, 0 );
```

Where the `remove_action` in an `add_action` with a lower priority number (9)

---

To remove the "Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty" message, use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_notice ( $message ) {
    // Equal to (Must be exactly the same).
    // If the message is displayed in another language, adjust where necessary!
    if ( $message == 'Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty.' ) {
        return false;
    }   
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'filter_woocommerce_add_notice', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the answer from @7uc1f3r and some other tutorials I was checking recently, I discovered that this also does the trick:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', '__return_null' );
```

Comment: This will indeed work **BUT** with this answer **ALL notifications will be hidden!** so not only this specific notification but every notification which is normally displayed in WooCommerce